# Help with installing Node.js on ubuntu unity

Tags: unity, nodejs

As the title suggests I need help with installing node.js on my acer chromebook with ubuntu unity, which is updated to the latest version. I need this for school and this is literally my first time using this OS. If there's a guide, tutorial, or anything that can help me without being too technical I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) yet?

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands for node.js v6:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: There's no need to go to their website and download the file from there? Like how you first install crouton? A command is all that's needed?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. From their website:https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Neat. Thanks for this. Saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Actually if you're still around I have another question. Is that command one line? or is it separated by the "|" symbol?

Comment: One line. That is a pipe